# Ruby on rails from console - (Table doesn't exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning RoR in Windows 7 with InstantRails.

I got into sqlite3 successfully and created a table named Trades with a handful of columns. I got out of that and into ruby console.

```
>> class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base; end
=> nil
>> trade = Trade.new
=> #<Trade barterID: nil, title: nil, message: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> trade.class
=> Trade(Table doesn't exist)
```

I double-checked that by getting back into sqlite3 and it's definitely there. I know the table isn't named "Trade" so I tried re-naming is as Trade, but it gave even more errors. I read that the table name should be in plural format, so I think I have that part right.

Any help on why it says the table doesn't exist? I'll give any details I haven't thought of.

Comment: The ` #<Trade barterID: nil, title: ...` indicates that the table is there and Rails knows what it looks like. The `barterID` column is rather suspicious though. Get rid of that column, add an `id` column, and try again. Then learn about [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). Rails likes to do things its own way.

Comment: have you a) checked `log/development.log` for the queries that are send to the db b) the environment that you are running your console in and that it matches the db that you created the table in

Comment: the best solution I think is to install linux and work with rails on it. seriously - I've never thought that I'll be in love with ubuntu like now ;)

Comment: please show us your migration! And if you learn linux dont use a distribution with a GUI thats for the guys that dont really know what they are doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, you have to do a total abstraction of your DB. Whatever you work with sqlite or mysql the steps are the same (except the first configuraion, but sqlite doesn't need).

The normal process is the following :

1. Generate a Model with rails generator

   rails generate model Trade
2. Edit the associated migration file, (something like 2012xxxxxxxx_create_trades.rb in `db/migrate/`) and put it the schema of Trade. [syntax here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)
3. Run `rake db:migrate` in order to apply the changes to the database
4. Use your Model

Answer (score 7):

rails g model Trade will give you a correct template, but if you just want to fix your migration file, please make sure you create this table: **trades (plural not singular)**.

Rails will give you (Table doesn't exist) error if you have trade(singular) table in the database. I think the error is kinds of misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the table manually ? If so, it isn't the "Rails way" of creating tables/models. You should use a rails Generator :

```
rails g model Trade
```

The generator will create a model class in app/models and a migration file in the db/migrate directory. Then, add the db columns using the [migration DSL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).